# How to reject a forced update by GIT on client side when doing a git fetch or git pull?

Tags: git, git-push, git-fetch

It is possible to deny forced pushes on server-side by setting [receive.denyNonFastForwards](http://%20https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_code_receive_denynonfastforwards_code) or by [adding a git hook](https://github.com/kyanny/git-hooks-detect-force-update) (or in a different way for special GIT servers like Gerrit or Github). I would like to reject a forced update on client side (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319110/how-to-detect-a-forced-update)), when doing a `git fetch` or `git pull` or a `git pull --rebase`. If I don't have access to the GIT server to reject forced pushes (or if I don't trust the server because others have access too), I might want GIT to stop with an error before changing any refs when a forced push was done. This could help to notice attackers changing the remote or if I simple want to know if somebody changes my commits (yes, if I really want to avoid somebody else committing using my name, I need sign my commits using my key).

I seems not to be possible to run code after a [fetch or pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623208/how-to-execute-a-command-right-after-a-fetch-or-pull-command-in-git) command using hooks. I parse the output of `git fetch` and raise an error if "forced update" has been printed. But it would actually be better to detect this before refs are changed.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `remote.fetch` line gfrom git config to remove "+" from it, Then non-fastforward fetches would fail. It does not protect though from branch removal

Answer (score 0):

[max630's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55006308/1057485) is fine, but let's just note that when you only want to *check* what would have been fetched/pulled you can, without any config hack, go for the dry run :

```
git fetch --dry-run
```

and you'll see what *would* have been, without modifying anything in your remote-tracking branches.

No similar trick for pull, but since a pull is a fetch + a merge, go for the dry-run fetch beforehand and you'll know what would have been pulled.

---

The limit of this technique, as [kan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988424/how-to-reject-a-forced-update-by-git-on-client-side-when-doing-a-git-fetch-or-gi/55006381?noredirect=1#comment96768482_55006381) rightfully noted in comments below, is its non-atomicity : the remote state could change in between your `fetch --dry-run` and the real thing seconds later. No harm to know it exists, anyway.

Comment: Just keep in mind, that this is not atomic: i.e. if you do `--dry-run`, see if all is ok, and then if you do `pull` - you could override if someone else force-pushed meanwhile.

Comment: @kan Excellent point. It doesn't make the option useless, but in this specific case I think you're right to stress it, since OP's main concern seems to be security.