# git pull ignores current work directory in shell script

Tags: git, shell, sh, git-pull, cd

I'm trying to get some sort of auto-deployment working.

My current post-update hook looks like follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

for ref in $@
do
        if [ $ref = "refs/heads/master" ]
        then
                echo "Deploying $ref to dev-domain"
                cd ~/www/dev-domain
                echo "" > system/lock
                if ! git pull --ff-only
                then
                        echo "Failed to pull"
                        exit
                fi
                if ! system/migrateDatabase
                then
                        echo "Failed to migrate"
                        exit
                fi
                rm system/lock
        fi
done
```

But all I get is this:

```
remote: Deploying refs/heads/master to dev-domain
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: Failed to pull
```

The file lock-file will be placed in the correct place, though.

So, to me it seems like `git pull` somehow ignored the current working directory... How do I get around this?
Or am I missing something different?

Comment: I forgot to say that if I'd run the commands directly (in an interactive shell) it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unset `GIT_DIR` before the `git pull`.

If you don't,  git would use the [variable `GIT_DIR`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Repository-Locations) instead of PWD.
cd-ing changes the PWD not the GIT_DIR.

As mention in [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair)'s article "[Missing git hooks documentation](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/)", `GIT_DIR` is set by hooks.

See more in "[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534486/6309) by [Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen).