# Creating a `git pre-recieve hook` that fails when working directory isn't clean

Tags: git, githooks

**Situation**

I have a copy of a git repository on my local system, as well as a second one on a remote server (both non-bare).  Due to environmental constraints, I'm forced to use Git 1.8 on both.

On the server, I have `[receive] denyCurrentBranch = ignore` in `.git/config` , and `git reset --hard` in `.git/hooks/post-receive` .  This allows me to emulate the `denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead` behavior.

I'm trying to add a `pre-receive` hook that will fail when I don't have a clean head.

**Attempt**

On the server, if I run `git status` I have the following:

```
[server test_app]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I had planned to add `git status` in the hook, something like this (pseudo-bash):

```
((git status | grep "On branch master" | wc -l) == 1) && ((git status | grep "nothing to commit, working directory clean" | wc -l) == 1) && (exit 0)
exit 1
```

To test if this was possible, I tried the following in my hook

```
git status
exit 1
```

**Results**

When I try to push, I get the following:

```
Pushing to ssh://.../test_app
remote: # On branch master[K
remote: # Changes not staged for commit:[K
remote: #   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)[K
remote: #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)[K
remote: #[K
remote: #   deleted:    bin/README[K
remote: #[K
remote: # Untracked files:[K
remote: #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)[K
remote: #[K
remote: #   COMMIT_EDITMSG[K
remote: #   HEAD[K
remote: #   ORIG_HEAD[K
remote: #   config[K
remote: #   description[K
remote: #   hooks/[K
remote: #   index[K
remote: #   info/[K
remote: #   logs/[K
remote: #   objects/[K
remote: #   refs/[K
remote: no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")[K
remote: I will fail[K
To ssh://.../test_app
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://.../test_app'
```

**Conclusion**

I assume this means I'm misunderstanding what state git is in at the pre-receive hook.  What should I have in my pre-receive (or some other) hook to prevent an update when the working directory isn't clean?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/ and [reset hard on git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531309/reset-hard-on-git-push) , I've found out that pre-receive sets the working directory and the GIT_DIR environmental variable to the .git/ folder.

Thus the following is sufficient

```
git --git-dir=. --work-tree=$PWD/.. status
```

The entire hook for anyone interested:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=`git --git-dir=. --work-tree=$PWD/.. status`
val=`echo $data | grep "working directory clean" | wc -l`

if [ $val -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "All good"
  exit 0
else
  echo "I will fail"
  echo $data
  exit 1
fi
```